# AJAX POST request to external domain using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

I'm trying to do an AJAX POST request to an external domain from a post metabox in WordPress. 
I know that it's not possible to do it directly because of cross domain access errors. As far as I know it's also not possible to do it simply by using PHP code like

```
if ( isset ( $_POST( 'button_name' ) ) ) { .. }
```

since all the metaboxes are inside the wordpress post form.

So this is what I came up with:

1. I use the wp_localize_script() function to make the php variables available in the js-file (this works). The localized variable is `ajax_request_args`.
2. The javascript file looks like this:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

       $('#button').click( function() {

           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: php_post.php,
               data: ajax_request_args,
               success: function(data) {
               alert(data["success"] + " " + data["code"]);
               },
               dataType: 'json'
           });
       });
   });
   ```
3. The php_post.php looks similar to this:

   ```
   if (is_ajax()) {

       ...

       if (isset($_POST["arg_1"]) && !empty($_POST["arg_1"])) {
           $response = wp_remote_post( $external_url, array(
               'method' => 'POST',
               'body' => $args,
               'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ),
               'timeout' => 90,
               'blocking' => true
           ) ); 

       $return = $_POST; 
       $return['success_message'] = $response['success_message'];
       $return['code'] = $response['code'];

       $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
       echo json_encode($return); 
       }
   }
   ```

The AJAX request works without the POST request in the php file, for example when I set

```
$response['success_message'] = 'success';
$response['code'] = '1234';
```

and delete the `wp_remote_post()`part.

The POST request to the external domain also works when I call it directly using a button click like

```
<?php
if (isset( $_POST['test-maintenance-btn'])){

    ...

    $response = wp_remote_post( $external_url, array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'body' => $args,
                'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ),
                'timeout' => 90,
                'blocking' => true
            ) ); 

}

?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="test-btn" name="test-btn" value="<?php _e('Execute', 'textdomain'); ?>">
</form>
```

The weird thing is that it doesn't work in connection. The Javascript should post to the php file which posts to the external server and returns the result to the ajax post request.

When I try to do the `wp_remote_post` (even if I don't use the result) I always get `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error"` in the console.

Could you help me find the problem and help me with the correct approach? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: what is the output of the server error logs when you get that 500 error?

Comment: @Ron "POST /wp-content/plugins/myplugin/php_post.php HTTP/1.1" 500 0 "https://website.ch/wp-admin/post.php?post=160&action=edit&lang=de&message=4" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0" "website.ch"

Comment: check your .htaccess files and see if they overwrite these requests.. in WP 500 errors are mostly due to .htaccess files. You can also enable error_reporting(1); in the files you are posting to, and on the server's php.ini, (if this is not a production server), to find out why you are getting error 500. Since this error is serverside, I am not able to determine why exactly you get it